# how do I launch multiple startup tasks at a build time docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to launch multiples startup scripts where it automates my ci/cd tasks, but however, I am just getting the response of the entry point.sh, how can I force to execute other scripts?

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=$',\n' ## set IFS to break on comma or newline

for host in $HOSTS; do
    ## mkdir -p "letsencrypt/live/${host}/fullchain.pem"
    echo "mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/${host}/fullchain.pem"
done
```

init-letsencrypt.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "cool"
```

```
xxxxx:~/xx$ docker-compose logs nginx
Attaching to platform_nginx_1
nginx_1            | mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/domain.io/fullchain.pem
nginx_1            | mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/www.domain.io/fullchain.pem
nginx_1            | mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/api.domain.io/fullchain.pem
nginx_1            | mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/app.domain.io/fullchain.pem

FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

# Install certbot for letsencrypt certificates
RUN apk add --no-cache certbot

COPY . /etc/nginx/

# Directory needed for LetEncrypt certificates renewal
RUN mkdir /var/lib/certbot

# Add scripts and auto-renewal scripts
COPY ./bin/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY ./bin/init-letsencrypt.sh /init-letsencrypt.sh

# Make them executable
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /init-letsencrypt.sh

# Install certificates and launch
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: A container runs one process and one process only.  So the basic choices here are to run multiple containers, or for the main container process to be a script that does one thing and then does the other.  If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` at the end of the script then you can easily run the same image with the other command, `docker run ... your-image /init-letsencrypt.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

To run something at build time, you should use `RUN`.

`CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` are used to launch the main process of your container. A container is "just" a process that is encapsulated in namespaces, basically. A container runs until this process stops or dies. When you specify you `entrypoint.sh` as an entrypoint, you are saying that the main process of you container is this script. To say it differently : the only goal of this container is to execute this script then die

You should use`RUN` to launch both of your scripts, then `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to launch your nginx (most probably `ENTRYPOINT`, you wilk get why if you read the docs ;))